# Don't rewrite URLs which represent files

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
# These settings routes all traffic, except concrete files, to the dispatcher

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is that it does route concrete files to the dispatcher :(

How can I make it so URLs like `http://site.com/style.css` are ignored?

Comment: you'll want to add 'apache' tag for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and let me know:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L]
```

You were rewriting everything to the index.php, this will check if the file/folder/symlink exists and then load the file if it does.

Comment: thanks that works, but I needed to prepend the subdirectory to index.php. Is there any way I can ommit that and make the rewriting work regardless in what directory my script is? Like before, but to work with direct file links :)

Comment: Can you give me examples please?

Comment: well for example, if the script (index.php) is in root/abc/ I have to add `RewriteRule . /abc/index.php` otherwise I get redirected to the root. I was hoping there's a way to do this without me having to specify that "/abc/" path in htaccess

Comment: I assume you have multiple folders?

Comment: if you need to load the index.php from the sub-folder and not the root try to copy this to the sub-folder (or you can create symbolic link). the other option you can put rules that check for specific folders but that can be messy